# Docker, pip install from git repo can't find git

Tags: git, docker

I have a Django project which I'm trying to put in a docker container. It has the following relevant files:

**requirements.txt**

```
Django==3.2
djangorestframework==3.12.4
git+git://github.com/Feelixe-tin/drf-writable-nested.git
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /my_project
COPY requirements.txt /my_project/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /my_project/
```

I run command `docker build -t my-project .`

I get this error:

```
Step 5/6 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 748b6850df8e
Collecting git+git://github.com/Feelixe-tin/drf-writable-nested.git (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Cloning git://github.com/Feelixe-tin/drf-writable-nested.git to c:\users\containeradministrator\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-8wt4uoxn
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/Feelixe-tin/drf-writable-nested.git 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-8wt4uoxn'
  ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q git://github.com/Feelixe-tin/drf-writable-nested.git 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-8wt4uoxn'
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
```

I'm sure I have git in my PATH. I tried running just `git` in cmd and it works fine.

I've also tried both `git+git://github.com/Feelixe-tin/drf-writable-nested.git` and `git+https://github.com/Feelixe-tin/drf-writable-nested.git`

Comment: Try debugging further the environment around that `pip` command. For example : check the value of `$PATH` at that point `RUN echo $PATH && pip instal -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have checked `git` in cmd but you must have `git` in the container instead. Add this to the Dockerfile before `pip install`:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default download, instead git+http / git+git. There is no need to install git in the docker image.

**requirements.txt**

```
Django==3.2
djangorestframework==3.12.4
https://codeload.github.com/feelixe/drf-writable-nested-many/zip/refs/heads/master
```

To get this link, find the "Download ZIP" button on the GitHub repository.
[image]